# Python module cli bash: command not found

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a cli tool using python but whenever I try to run the command in terminal i get the error 'bash: command not found'. The python modules installs without any errors. I'm on macos and using python version: 3.9.4. I think this may be a PATH issue but currently unsure.

Here is the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'mycommand',
    version = '0.1.0',
    packages = ['mycommand'],
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'mycommand = mycommand.__main__:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

Here is the **main**.py:

```
import sys

def main():
    print('in main')
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    print('count of args :: {}'.format(len(args)))
    for arg in args:
        print('passed argument :: {}'.format(arg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope somebody can help me with this.

This is the tutorial I have followed: https://trstringer.com/easy-and-nice-python-cli/

Comment: How are you trying to "run the command"?

Comment: I'm just trying to run the command in the macos terminal. Like this: 'mycommand'.

Comment: Did you type `./mycommand`?  Unlike Windows, the current directory on Unix-based systems is not included in the path.

Comment: I have just tried that and it returns 'No such file or directory.' The shell I'm using is bash if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your layout is like that:

```
setup.py
mycommand/main.py
```

then the entrypoint is simply `mycommand.main:main`:

- `mycommand/main.py` -> `mycommand.main`
- `:main` -> `def main()`

Comment: Yes, my layout is exactly the same except main.py is __main__.py and the setup.py entry point reflects that.

Comment: lol you can escape `__main__` between backquotes :)

Comment: If it helps this is the tutorial i have been following: https://trstringer.com/easy-and-nice-python-cli/

Comment: how you do you install the package ? `python setup.py develop` ? `pip install -e .` ?

Comment: I install it using 'pip install -e .' in the install.sh file, i have also tried using the command on its own. Also the package install successfully without any errors.

Comment: are you using are virtualenv, is it activate ? your sample works for me

Comment: Hi, just figured it out, i was running install.sh wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JakeHughesMusic can you tell how were u running install.sh. Because I am also facing the same issue. And I cant figure out what I am doing wrong I tried everything suggested here

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `scripts` keyword argument.

First add a file called `mycommand` (note that you should not have any extension) in the same directory as main.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from mycommand.main import main
main()
```

then edit your setup.py like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'mycommand',
    version = '0.1.0',
    packages = ['mycommand'],
    scripts=['mycommand/mycommand'],
)
```

Then when you install this package you will be able to call `mycommand`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. I have just tried this but i'm still not having much look. If it helps the tutorial I followed is here: https://trstringer.com/easy-and-nice-python-cli/

Comment: Where did you put the `mycommand` file? If it is in the same directory as main.py then it should be `scripts=['mycommand/mycommand'],`. I will update the answer

Comment: Hi, i have just tried that and still no luck. I even downloaded the code from the tutorial: https://trstringer.com/easy-and-nice-python-cli/ and I'm still getting the same 'command not found'.

Comment: Have you installed it using the `install.sh` script? Try reinstalling after the changes

Comment: Yes i have tried that aswell but still have no luck.

Comment: I cloned the repo and added the file as in the answer and it is working for me...

Comment: May you tell me the steps you took to get it working for you. I just tried cloning it again and still no look.

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/trstringer/pycli.git`, add file `pycli` in inner most folder (same as `__main__.py`) and put `from pycli.__main__ import main; main()`. Then change `setup.py`: remove the `entry_points` and add `scripts=['pycli/pycli']`. Finally run `./install.sh` (careful as it calls pip3, if you have pip with some other alias then replace it). Then I am able to call `pycli` and I get some output

Comment: What shell are you using as i am using bash. Also do you know if this would matter?

Comment: I am using zsh on mac but it should behave the same as bash in this instance. which os are you on?

Comment: I am on mac aswell and also using zsh i got a little mixed up with bash.

Comment: Just figured it out, i was running install.sh wrong the entire time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatteoZanoni I did the same steps as u suggested and its still not working I am getting command not found